# I've got 6 related tables. I would like to display information from all these tables on one page

Tags: oracle-apex

```
Table 1 : Company Information 
Table 2 : Financial 
Table 3 : Media 
Table 4 : SWOT Analysis 
Table 5 : Events 
Table 6 : Interests
```

I will like to create **one page** to display all these tables in Oracle Application Express.

However,I do not want all the rows of data to be displayed. I will only like to see related data when a specific company is selected.

For example, 
select Ansa Mcal (then all the information from the tables relating to ANSA Mcal will display)
select Nedcom (then all the information from the tables relating to Nedcom will display).

Thank you for your help.
Please be as detailed as possible as I am a beginner in APEX.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation on apex.oracle.com . There is a 2-day tutorial there: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21679/toc.htm . Go through it. If you're a beginner, this will take you through the basics which is something you really should get a grip on before diving in head-first. What you're asking is a couple of simple classic reports with a sql query with a where-clause referencing a page item. To be honest, we should not figure this out for you unless you're really in trouble!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to make a new blank page with the name of ABC.2nd step is to click on edit and add 6 regions in the same page with the names of your tables respectively.

Create Report for your each table while selecting the region of your desired table to  be displayed i-e if you want to show the information of Financial table then you have to select the financial Region for that table.

Regards,